# Querying a primary key through java client - Aerospike

Tags: java, aerospike

I'm trying to emulate the query `Select * from namespace.set where pk="something"` through aeropsike's java client. I know that we can query on a secondary index through "Filter", and create "PredExp" for other predicates, but I'm unable to figure out how we can query on a primary key.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit** : I have multiple bins in my set, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You just have to create a "new key" while querying through the java aerospike client.

`Record record = aerospikeClient.get(null, new Key(namespace, cacheName, key), binNames)`

Refer to the discussion: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/primary-key-search/558/6

Comment: Good question and answer. You can find implementation for SQL equivalents in the aerospike/aerospike-jdbc repo. See this blog post https://dev.to/aerospike/introducing-aerospike-jdbc-driver-4l14